# URL token not working in webpart properties

Tags: sharepoint-online, url, web-part-property

In a SharePoint Online webpart page, I added an image viewer web part. The following URLs work:

```
/sites/a6c36769/SiteAssets/Tri.jpg
../SiteAssets/Tri.jpg
```

(The full URL works because it is shortened to the first working URL listed above)

However, I cannot find a URL token that will link to the image. I have tried

```
~site/SiteAssets/Tri.jpg
~sitecollection/SiteAssets/Tri.jpg
```

I have also tried linking to the image in a library other than Site Assets with the same results.

The page containing the web part is
`https://[companyName].sharepoint.com/sites/a6c36769/Pages/default.aspx`

Ultimately, I would like to use the JSLink property of webparts, and I believe the path to the .js file was not working. That put me on to this trouble with images. I was keen to use the token because of a [troubleshooting post](http://therelentlessfrontend.com/2014/02/27/jslink-sharepoint-2013-not-working/) that claimed URL tokens had to be used with JSLink and that other types of URLs would not work.